# PHP - Create array with key from text string

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have simple text string, it is looking like that:

```
30143*1,30144*2,30145*3,30146*5,30147*5
```

And i have to transform this text string to array with this structure:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product] => 30143 [qty] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [product] => 30144 [qty] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [product] => 30145 [qty] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [product] => 30146 [qty] => 4 ) [4] => Array ( [product] => 30147 [qty] => 5 ) )
```

Is it even possible and if so how?

I found this:

```
$myString = "9,admin@example.com,8";
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

But this is only creating the array with no keys and wtih example there is no way to get the `qty` key with `*`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `explode()` is a good start. Now you want to look into `array_map()` and then use `explode()` inside `array_map()` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You need to iterate through all the `30143*1` items. `array_map` do this job for you.

```
function getPieces($val) {
    $pieces  = explode('*', $val);
    return ['product' => $pieces[0], 'qty' => $pieces[1]];
}

$str = '30143*1,30144*2,30145*3,30146*5,30147*5';
$result = array_map('getPieces', explode(',', $str));

var_dump($result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'product' => string '30143' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'product' => string '30144' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'product' => string '30145' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'product' => string '30146' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '5' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'product' => string '30147' (length=5)
      'qty' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be one of the possible ways:

```
$string = '30143*1,30144*2,30145*3,30146*5,30147*5';

$products = explode(',',$string);
$result = array();
foreach ($products as $productAndQuantity) {
    $result[] = array_combine(array('product', 'qty'), explode('*', $productAndQuantity));
}

var_dump($result);
```

output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(5) "30143"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(5) "30144"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(5) "30145"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(5) "30146"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product"]=>
    string(5) "30147"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hooray for [regex solutions](http://regular-expressions.info)…

```
$str = '30143*1,30144*2,30145*3,30146*5,30147*5';

if (preg_match_all('/(?<product>[^*]+)\*(?<qty>[^,]+),?/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    $result = array_map(
        function ($match) { return array_intersect_key($match, array_flip(['product', 'qty'])); },
        $matches
    );
    print_r($result);
}
```

The `preg_match_all` call already [mostly does what you want](https://regex101.com/r/cH8vT4/1), `$matches` is already sort of the expected result, it just has some additional entires which the `array_intersect_key` gets rid of.

Comment: You can also unset the 3 numeric keys.

Comment: Yes, I could. Wouldn't say that's necessarily easier though.

Answer (score 0):

@deceze variant:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<product>\d+)\*(?<qty>\d+)~', $str, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($result as &$m) { unset($m[0], $m[1], $m[2]); }

print_r($result);
```